# NullPointerException and LoadException when using variables from one controller when initializing another. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, fxml, fxmlloader

I am developing an app on netbeand and SceneBuilder with JavaFX and FXML files. I have different controllers for diferent content that popup in the main window. I call from the main controller for the FXML to popup, that has it's own sepparate controller. Here is the funcition in the main controller that calls for the new content:

```
public void mostrar_alumno(Alumno a) throws IOException {
    centro.getChildren().clear();
    FXMLLoader visualizador_alumno = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/visualizador_alumno/FXMLVisualizadorAlumno.fxml"));
    centro.getChildren().add(visualizador_alumno.load());
    FXMLVisualizadorAlumnoController controlador_visualizador_alumno = visualizador_alumno.getController();
    controlador_visualizador_alumno.setAlumno(a);
    boton_crear.setDisable(true);
}
```

Sorry for spanish names in the variables >:)

The thing is that with `controlador_visualizador_alumno.setAlumno(a);` I set that variable on the controller. This is the code from the other controller, the ones that has to popup:

```
public class FXMLVisualizadorAlumnoController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ImageView foto;
@FXML
private TextField nombre;
@FXML
private TextField apellidos;
@FXML
private TextField correo;
private Tutorias misTutorias;
private Alumno alumno;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    misTutorias = AccesoBD.getInstance().getTutorias();
    //Inicializamos los datos.
    nombre.setText(alumno.getNombre());
    apellidos.setText(alumno.getApellidos());
    correo.setText(alumno.getEmail());               
    
}    

public void setAlumno(Alumno a) {
    alumno = a;
}
```

}

So when the method from the main window is called and the new content is supposed to popup I get a LoadException in `centro.getChildren().add(visualizador_alumno.load());` and a NullPointerException in `nombre.setText(alumno.getNombre());`

I guess this is because `nombre.setText(alumno.getNombre());` is the initialize method and the variable `alumno` is seted from the first controller so I is not there yet, I am not sure. I will be very glad if you can help mi solve it.
Any help is good. Thank you for your time.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say:

> This is because `nombre.setText(alumno.getNombre());` is in the `initialize()`
> method and the variable `alumno` is set from the first controller so it
> is not there yet.

To be precise, the `initialize()` method is invoked as part of the call to `load()`, which necessarily happens before you have access to the controller.

All you need to do is move the code that depends on `alumno` to the `setAlumno(...)` method. This makes semantic sense too (when you change `alumno`, update the text fields that display its data):

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    misTutorias = AccesoBD.getInstance().getTutorias();
    //Inicializamos los datos.
    
}    

public void setAlumno(Alumno a) {
    alumno = a;
    nombre.setText(alumno.getNombre());
    apellidos.setText(alumno.getApellidos());
    correo.setText(alumno.getEmail());               
}
```

Comment: Most simple solutions are sometimes the hardest to figure out hahahhahaha, thank you very much, problem solved.